# Excel Array formula to count moving average outliers

Tags: excel

I've tried a few things on this and settled on a 'cheap' solution. Wanted to know if this can be done directly and more elegantly.

**Problem Statement and Sample Data**
Assume we have a table in excel with ~200 columns and a large number of rows (~10k).

Sample Data:

| identifier | val1 | val2 | val3 | ... | val200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 100 | 102 | 34 | ... | 89 |

We want to add a column at the end that shows us how many "moving average" outliers exist. A moving average outlier is defined as a point that is outside the range (mean - 2 * std deviations, mean + 2 * std deviations), where the mean and std dev is calculated using the **previous** 10 values (therefore its a moving average outlier).
We will not test the first 10 values. But from val11, the **previous** 10 values will be used to form the window and we want to test if the value is an outlier.

**My Solution so far**
I created another table of same dimensions as the original. In cells from val11 (to val200, for all columns), I put in the formula below in the new table. And then, I can simply sum the columns in each row in the new table.
Assume val11 is on X2 in the "shocks" worksheet (for first row):
=IF(OR(shocks!X2<AVERAGEA(shocks!D2:W2)-2*STDEVA(shocks!D2:W2),shocks!X2>AVERAGEA(shocks!D2:W2)+2*STDEVA(shocks!D2:W2)),1,"")

**But if possible, I want to avoid having a second table since it bloats and slows down the file. Any help would be greaty appreciated**

Comment: This will always be slow, since there are a lot of calculations. The helper table is probably the fastest way to do that, anyway.

Comment: If you have Excel 365, you can use Let to avoid calculating average and stdev twice, which should save a bit of time

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't heard of LET. Its very useful in general and should speed up this worsksheet too! :)